# Featherlight Gallery: get source element of current slide

Tags: gallery, featherlight.js

Is there a way to find the element that contains the href to the current featherlight content when cycling through a gallery?

Basically, I want to change the `.featherlight` background color to match that of the source element's background color.

As you can seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6jqo8dm/8/), if I click on an image, `.featherlight`'s background color matches that of the anchor that opened it. I would like the background color to change as I cycle through the gallery, so that `.featherlight` matches the anchor thumbnail's background color. Is there a way to get that information?

Thanks,
Scott

**UPDATE: For anyone seeking the solution, I edited the jsfiddle above so that the color change now works. Thanks to Marc-André.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe what you are looking for is `$currentTarget`.

Example of usage in [this wiki page](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/wiki/Gallery:-showing-a-caption)

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed.